# How to build minimal static Qt 5.2 32 bit library on 64 bit Linux Mint?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

My system is Linux Mint 16 x86_64. I need to build minimal static Qt 5.2 library from sources without some modules (declarative,  multimedia, etc) and without some features. Which configure options I need? Now I have build and link errors (cannot find qxcb, problems with qtdeclarative/lib/libQt5Qml.a', needed by `../../lib/libQt5Positioning.a')
My configure options is:

```
./configure -static -release -opensource -confirm-license -platform linux-g++-32 -skip multimedia -skip declarative -no-compile-examples -nomake examples -no-openssl -prefix /usr/local/qt-release-static-32
```

Comment: Which features exactly would you like to exclude?

Comment: I want to exclude some features defined at qtbase/src/corelib/global/qfeatures.txt.

Comment: Why do you need a *static* Qt library? Releasing a proprietary software linked to it (without giving the end-user the ability to relink the application with his improved Qt) might be against the LGPL license of Qt. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8386335/841108)

Comment: We can open our sources.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: this is a programming site, note licensing. It is up to the OP to deal with the license question out of stackoverflow. I think the question is programmnig related here instead.

Answer (score 2):

configure Qt with `-qt-xcb` will build `libqxcb.a` in `qtbase/plugins/platforms/` which can solve cannot find qxcb link error.
But Qt still requires `libxcb >= 1.5` and `libxcb` will still be linked dynamically.

You can see `qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/xcb/README` and `qtbase/src/3rdparty/xcb/README` for detail.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following option for configure:

```
-no-feature-<feature> Do not compile in <feature>.

-feature-<feature> .. Compile in <feature>. The available features
                      are described in src/corelib/global/qfeatures.txt

-D <string> ........ Add an explicit define to the preprocessor.
```

Comment: @cybergnom: sudo apt-get install "^libxcb.*" libx11-xcb-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxrender-dev

Comment: @cybergnom: have you resolved the nitty-gritty details?

Comment: No, I could not. With Qt 4.8.5 everything is ok.

Comment: I think Qt5 does not support -no-feature configure options any more.